# Set of $3 \times 3$ matrices is the direct sum of subspace of strictly upper diagonal matrices and subspace of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang.

He claims that the sum of upper diagonal matrix and symmetric matrices gives $m \times m$ matrices.

Using an example of $3 \times 3$ matrix.
How does it have dimension $9$ when it is impossible to get a matrix

```
[ 1 2 3 
  4 5 6 
  7 8 9]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I find confusing your wording: can you give the exact chapter and section in Strang's book?

Comment: @DonAntonio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IdtqGM6KWU&t=515s#t=568.295658055 at around 13 min mark

Comment: You've quoted Strang wrongly. In the video, he says that the *sum* (not *union*) of (the subspace of) all symmetric matrices and (the subspace of) all *upper triangular* (not *"upper diagonal"* --- that term doesn't make any sense) gives you all square matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand now, and for example

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&\!-2&\!-4\\0&0&\!-2\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1&4&7\\4&5&8\\7&8&9\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Ah thanks. Will accept the answer when i can. Thanks!. Didnt think of it this way

Comment: The OP mentions "upper diagonal matrix" (???). I see you have "translated" it into "upper triangular matrix", maybe after having seen the video.

Comment: @JeanMarie Of course...the OP also says "union" when after watching the video for 1 minute it is obvious the intentio is "sum" .

Comment: @DonAntonio I have watched at the video: everything is clear now. I have thus modified my answer...

Answer (score 3):

I understand that the aim of the cited video is to prove that

$$dim(S+U)+dim(S\cap U)=dim(S)+dim(U)$$

Here is another way of looking at things.

Consider the space $V$ of  **strictly** upper triangular matrices. Let us name $M$ the set of all $3 \times 3$ matrices.

We can establish that $M = S \oplus V.$

This "direct sum" sign $\oplus$ (replacing the ordinary "plus" sign) means that any matrix in $M$ can be considered **in a unique way** as the sum of a symmetric matrix and of a **strictly** upper triangular matrix,

In other words, being given any $3 \times 3$ matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}r&s&\!t\\u&v&\!w\\x&y&z\end{pmatrix}$$

there exist a unique decomposition:

$$\tag{1}\begin{pmatrix}r&s&\!t\\u&v&\!w\\x&y&z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\b&d&e\\c&e&f\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&g&h\\0&0&i\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Important remark: it accounts in particular for the  desired number of dimensions (9=6+3).

Proof: Entries $r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z$ being given, we have to find $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$ and show that the latter values exist and are unique.
Relationship $(1)$ is equivalent to 9 relationships.

6 of them have immediate consequences: take

$$\tag{2}a:=r,b:=s \cdots f:=z.$$

For the remaining 3:

$$\tag{3}\begin{cases}s=b+g\\t=c+h \\ w=e+i\end{cases} \ \ \iff \ \ \begin{cases}g:=s-b\\ h:=t-c\\ i:=w-e\end{cases}$$

(explanation: $b,c,e$ are known quantities due to relationships $(2)$).